# Swift: UIButton edgeinsets applies after cell redrawn/scroll

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton, padding, uiedgeinsets

After couple of days struggling I wanted to ask you about UIButton title and image edge insets...

I have custom cell with button and on that button depends on cell type should be different icons and text but the requirement text should be centered and image could be left aligned or right. For that I'm setting edge insets during updating button tile and image. To keep it simple I hard coded image insets left to be 8 and the calculating left point of title from which text should start.

```
func setTitleWithImage(_ title: String, imageName: String) {
    self.btnStatus.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    self.btnStatus.setImage(UIImage(named: imageName), for: .normal)
    
    self.btnStatus.imageEdgeInsets.left = 8
    let btnWidth = btnStatus.frame.width
    let titleLabelWidth = btnStatus.titleLabel?.frame.width
    self.btnStatus.titleEdgeInsets.left = (btnWidth / 2) - (titleLabelWidth! / 2) - (btnStatus.imageView?.frame.width)! + self.btnStatus.imageEdgeInsets.left
}
```

The problem is that when tableview loaded it is wrong aligned but after scrolling/redraw cell it is aligned correctly. I tried different suggestions but no one helped me.

**Before scroll**

[image: Before Scroll]

**After scroll**

[image: After scroll]

To be more specific here is the whole project:

[Sources](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f0fnetp5xlity4r/CustomCellRoundCorners.zip?dl=0)

**UPDATED**

`ViewController` almost all for more detailed please download source

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 140
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.setTitleWithImage("DIFFERENT TEXT IS HERE ?", imageName: "icon")
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.setNeedsLayout()
    
    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Assuming that your `setTitleWithImage` works correctly, the obvious questions are: (1) where is this function called? (2) What do your overrides for the `UITableView` have in them?

Comment: @dfd: Updated, please have a look, for more detailed please download source it is really simple and small app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func alignTitleWithImageFrames () {
    let btnWidth = btnStatus.frame.width
    let titleLabelWidth = btnStatus.titleLabel?.frame.width
    self.btnStatus.titleEdgeInsets.left = (btnWidth / 2) - (titleLabelWidth! / 2) - (btnStatus.imageView?.frame.width)! + 13
    self.btnStatus.imageEdgeInsets.left = 8
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved a lot !

Comment: You should call align func from 2 places when setting title and image and from layoutSubviews func